# Char to Int - C++

Tags: c++, list, struct, char, int

I know there are already answered questions about it, but I have read most of them and still couldn't solve my problem. 
I have a program that will read notes, keep them in a list and give options to the user to delete, change, or select a specific note.

I'm using this struct:

```
struct List {
    char title [101];
    char text  [501];
    int cont; //code of the note.
    struct List* next;

};typedef List list;
```

I'm stuck at the point of selection, if the user types a * it must return all notes, and if the user type a number it must return only the corresponding note.

So far i just have this:

```
List* select (List *l, int v) {
   List *p = l;
   for (p = l; p != NULL; p = p -> next){
        if( p -> cont == v){
        cout << "\nTitle: " << p -> title << "\n";
        cout << "Text: " << p -> text <<  "\n";
        cout << "Code: " << p -> cont << "\n" << "\n";
        }
   }
```

how can I read a symbol in char and transform to int, to compare it with the code of the note.

sorry if i write something wrong, i'm brazilian and i have none practice for writing.

EDIT: 
Thank you so much guys, it realy realy helped me a lot and now i get to finish my work! :D

Comment: How are getting the input from the user currently?  Are there any bounds on what is a valid code of the note?

Comment: Does using this solve your poblem: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/ ?

Comment: as I am on the base of the program, I still have doubts whether to change or not the input method, for now I'm using a simple cin entry in the int main, and the code of each note consists of a number, incremented on every note added, so it begins in 0 to 1, 2 and so.

Comment: And for the atoi function, I've tried, in a diferent test program with only the entry and the return of a number,  but as I have to get one symbol as char the program returned me an error code, not even a code in ascii, I know it's weird, but it happened

Comment: @OliviaThebaldiGarcia You may have to end up changing your input method. You're very limited in your options when reading a char and wanting to convert it to an int because its not so much a conversion as it is a comparison. You can only compare and extract the respective equivalent.

Comment: Do you have to use `*` to represent all notes? Is it a requirement?

Comment: I figured I would have to do this sooner or later, other classmates said they get do do it in other ways but I still have my doubts, I can not imagine how they did it

Comment: @Javia1492, yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Get the input as a string

```
string str;
cin >> str;
```

If the string is a `*`

```
if (str == "*")
{
    // print out all notes
}
```

Else, attempt too convert string into number with [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/). Strtol gives better error checking than atol because it tells you whether the whole string was converted and if not, where so you can go look.

```
char * endp; 
long code;

code =  strtol(str.c_str(), // the string converted to characters
               &endp, // where in the string the number ended. 
               10); // the base of the number, base 10 in this case for       
                    // decimal. 16 if you want to input in hex. 
                    // Unlikely in this case.
if (*endp == '\0') // If the number didn't end didn't end at the end 
                   // of the string, the number is invalid
{
    // print note for code
}
```

<s>A quick note on `strtol(str.c_str(), &endp, 10);` and testing `endp`.</s>

This doesn't actually work. `endp` winds up pointing at a memory location that may not be valid by the time you get to check. Really, you need to get the char array out of the string and into something for which you can guarantee the scope.

The above warning is incorrect based on old, or faulty data. Thank you @TamásSzabó. Makes future code writing a wee bit simpler.

No std::string version is almost the same:

```
char str[64]; // allocate storage for a big number. 
cin.get(str, sizeof(str)); // read up to size of string -1 and null terminate
if ((str[0] == '*') && (str[1] == '\0'))
                   // first character in string is '*' and there 
                   // is no second character
{
    // print out all notes
}
else
{
    char * endp; 
    long code;

    code =  strtol(str, 
                   &endp, 
                   10);  
    if (*endp == '\0')  //this time endp will be valid 
    {
        // print note for code
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldnt OP use the same logic as your `if` statement for case `*` but also use it for ints? Such as, `if(str == "1")`, etc..? It may be inefficient depending on the number of notes allowed.

Comment: thats the problem, i can't limit the number of notes, so a can have 1 or 30 notes, how knows.

Comment: user4581301, i tried, but again as you said in the edit, it realy doesn't work and don't even fit in my program :/

Comment: @Javia1492 Could, but it would needlessly limit the possible number of notes.

Comment: @OliviaThebaldiGarcia, How does it not fit? Not allowed to use std::string?

Comment: @user4581301 Why would `endp` end up being invalid in your code? It can only become invalid if the content of `str` changes before you test `endp` which is clearly impossible here.

Comment: is for a work of college and my teacher forbade me to use string, he said it would not work to the implement that we'll do in the program, so I can only use char and int

Comment: @TamásSzabó The internals of std::string are not guaranteed to map to a c-style string so the result of c_str might not be in the string. Frankly, I don't know if there are any guarantees about where c_str's buffer is. I need to do some reading. C++11 makes better guarantees, but I can't be sure everyone reading this is using compliant compilers.

Comment: @user4581301 [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/): string::c_str(): Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current value of the string object.
This array includes the same sequence of characters that make up the value of the string object plus an additional terminating null-character ('\0') at the end.

Comment: All that says is you will get a pointer containing a c-style string. It says nothing about the lifetime of the pointed-to data. However, I've done some reading  and it looks like you're right. The lifetime is preserved until forced to change going back at least to C++98, and I don't think we really had a standard string before that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to only `char` and `int` types, you could try this:

```
char buf[10]; // Assuming that you won't have more than 10 characters in your number
char *endp;
cin >> buf; // This may cause you problems if the input string is more than 9 characters long!
```

From here on you can use user4581301's answer:

```
if ( (buf[0] == '*') && (buf[1] == '\0') )
{
 // Print all your notes here
}

code =  strtol(but, // the string converted to characters
               &endp, // where in the string the number ended. 
               10); // the base of the number, base 10 in this case for       
                    // decimal. 16 if you want to input in hex. 
                    // Unlikely in this case.
if (*endp == '\0') // If the number didn't end didn't end at the end 
                   // of the string, the number is invalid
{
    // print note for code
}
```

Comment: `cin.get(buf, sizeof(buf));` will limit reading size to the buffer's length

Comment: Also need to tweak `if (buf[0] == "*")` to `if (buf[0] == '*')` and should test buf[1] for null to disallow input of "*12345", etc...

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.